# Domino 9 FP10 xpages external JAR

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

While doing a Test upgrade from Domino 9 FP8 to Domino 9 FP10 HF197 on an application that uses an external JAR "com.google.gson" ran into an error of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:. The application works fine on the FP8 installation with the JAR in the NSF file.  But on the FP10 installation I had to copy the JAR in the jvm/lib/ext folder for the application to work. I read several posts and play around with the Build, Manifest and other settings but nothing made any different.  Can someone explain what I'm missing with the eclipse setup or does external JAR now need to go into the jvm/lib/ext folder ?  We also upgrading the Domino 10 are there any issues that I need to look out for like this ? 
Thank you
Bob

Comment: Maybe it worked in FP8 because of an updated java.policy file that allowed AllPermission while it fails in FP10 because the java.policy file has been set to default when you installed FP10?

Comment: I'll check but I did update the java.policy file. thanks

Comment: This is content of the java.pol file:
grant {
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
   permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${java.home}/lib/-", "read";  
};

Comment: Another thought: maybe the jar was already in the jvm/lib/ext folder in the FP8 install, but was removed with the FP10 upgrade. Seen that happening more than once. My advice would anyway be to store any 3rd party jars in the jvm/lib/ext folder.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but that not the case.  I'm testing the update on a test server against our Production environment FP8 which works without the gson lib in the ext folder.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get some "presents" when you update. You have already seen that the jars in the lib/ext.

However, this is also true about the lib/security directory. So any permissions you have set in the "java.policy" file will also be lost.

At some point you could use a "java.pol" file to put your own changes - but it appears that this does not work any more (see [comments in this article](https://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/java-security-in-ibm-domino/)).

So chances are that you need to re-add any customisations to the "java.policy" file :-)

/John

Comment: Thanks John, Good information but I did the java.pol after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

The GSon library should actually be available in a core Domino installation. The library is used in the Verse plugin. So no external lib needed

Comment: How can I verify that Gson library is indeed available in the core Domino install ? On my FP8 development server I had to import the jar file into the NSF.